# I want to get characters out of a string in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, substring, trim

How can i write this SQL formula in Crystal Reports?

```
SUBSTRING(text, 6, 4))
```

Sample String:  `A003-A113-02`

Using `SUBSTRING` in SQL, output = `A113`

Tried to use the `Trim` function, but not getting any good result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trim` removes whitespace-characters at the beginning and end of the string.

The equivalent of the SQL `SUBSTRING`-function in Crystal Reports is the `Mid`-Function:

```
Mid("A003-A113-02",6,4)
```

Comment: I tried to use the mid function but did not return any values.

{DIS_COMMODITY_MAINTAIN.ID}= MID ({?Pm-Command.COMMODITY_CODE},6,4)

This instance is inside a sub-report and ?Pm-Command.COMMODITY_CODE is being called from the main report.

Comment: Please check if you get the correct result from Mid-function in the main report. If yes, then the problem must be elsewhere. In this case, I recommend you to mark this question as answered and ask a new question with enough detail of that sub-report linking problem.

Comment: @GaryReal sounds like you have a problem with the scope of your fields.  When you have a subreport in your main report, the fields in the subreport are out of scope from the main report and the fields in the main report are out of scope from the subreport.  To get around this you will need to use `Shared` variables to effectively pass values between your main report and subreports.  I agree with MatSnow that you should probably address this in a new question though since this one has been answered completely.  Give it a shot yourself first though!